# C# - Trying to return a generic type T for different handlers

Tags: c#, generics, casting

Goal:

1. In Program.cs I call different command handlers but I want them to return `CustomerResponse<T>` - so each command handler can return their own type for type T

CustomerResponse:

```
public class CustomerResponse<T>
{
    public T Response { get; set; } // so other handlers can return their own response
}
```

ICommandHandler:

```
public interface ICommandHandler
{
    CustomerRespone<T> Handle<T>(T details);
}
```

CommandHandler:

```
public interface CustomerCommandHandler : ICommandHandler
{
    // injecting our service in ctor

    public CustomerResponse<T> Handle<T>(T details)
    {
        // result is of type CustomerResponse<Operation> but we can't return directly
        // because it can't be implicitly casted to CustomerResult<T>
        var result = _customerService.CustomerOperation(details);
        
        // doesn't do what i expect it to do at runtime
        return (CustomerResponse<T>)(object)result;
    }
}
```

Program.cs:

```
var result = _customerHandler.Handle(CustomerDetails details);
```

Issues:

- The type of result in program.cs will be `CustomerDetails`
- and so I will get a casting error for type `CustomerResponse<Operation>` to `CustomerResponse<CustomerDetails>`
- We want to return `CustomerResponse<Operation>`

This is so we can have multiple handlers which can return their own CustomerResponse

Comment: Maybe I need to rethink the design? (seems possible to me though haha)

Comment: Then give the Handle method two generic parameters when in Type and out Type differ?

Comment: Maybe elaborate a bit about the type you want to return here. You just thrown in the name operation for the class here in but with more details someone might have a better idea.

Comment: I want to return CommandResponse<Operation> which is what the service returns for this specific handler.... but since each handler has a different argument Type and return Type.. I think in my scenario its returning the argument Type... which is CustomerDetails

Comment: Would it help to show how my service looks like? the one thats returning operation?

Comment: Why not just use two generic params as stated by Ralf? One defining the type of input, one defining the expected output: CustomerResponse<U> Handle<T, U>(T details)?

Comment: ohhhhh... sorry - i didn't know ypu can use two params lol I'll give it a go now

Comment: you can use as many as you see need for ;)

Comment: The thing with generics is that without any restrictions you can store it, wrap it, pass it around etc. But you cannot use it in any kind of logic. So if your Handle takes an object T as input, it *has to* return the same object, wrapped in a CustomerResponse. but otherwise unchanged. I'm not sure what the exact intent is, but this likely indicate a fundamental problem in your design.

Comment: Fundamental problem? IMHO the  "CustomerResponse<U> Handle<T, U>(T details)"-type of interface is commonly seen in the CQRS-pattern and no indication of any design-issue.

Comment: @JonasH you might be right there! I'm just trying to make my code more reusable. so every handler can return the same type rather than all of them returning separate types to the calling class. Who knows maybe its better do it that way instead

Comment: That worked @SanchoPanza. If you want you or Ralf can create an answer and I will accept it as the correct one. Thank you

Comment: @SanchoPanza Sure, for an *interface*. But you need to define actual types for T and U *somewhere* , at least if you want the input and output to be related in any way. Or use restrictions so you have some knowledge about the types.

Answer (score -1):

Your interface `ICommandHandler` specifies exactly one thing: Whenever you put in something of a type `T`, you get a response of type `CustomerReponse<T>`. If your implementation wants to take in a `CustomerDetails` object and create a `CustomerResponse<Operation>`, it cannot implement this interface.

To me, it seems like the return type does depend on the type of command you are actually executing and thus, you cannot create a single interface as an umbrella. To do the latter, you would have to go to a more generic command pattern.